Permission Error When Executing Vertex AI Fine Tuning Job with Node.js: Service Account Roles Insufficient?
I'm using a pipeline job to fine tune a text-bison model with Vertex AI on GCP. My API is logged using a dedicated service account. It has the roles : Vertex AI Service Agent and Service Accounts User.
I'm using this Node.js code :
import aiplatform from '@google-cloud/aiplatform';

class ModelTuningController {
  initiateModelTuning = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { modelDisplayName = 'fineTunedTest' } = req.body;

    const { PipelineServiceClient } = aiplatform.v1;

    const location = 'us-central1';
    const project = 'projectID';
    const model = 'text-bison@001';

const pipelineClient = new PipelineServiceClient({
  apiEndpoint: `${location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com`,
  keyFilename: config.vector_store_key_filename,
});

const parameters = {
  source_model: { stringValue: model },
  train_dataset: {
    stringValue: 'gs://path/file.jsonl',
  },
  tuned_model_display_name: {
    stringValue: modelDisplayName,
  },
  epochs: {
    numberValue: 4,
  },
  learning_rate_multiplier: {
    numberValue: 1,
  },
};

const runtimeConfig = {
  gcsOutputDirectory: 'gs://output-path',
  parameterValues: parameters,
};

try {
  const parent = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}`;
  const pipelineJob = {
    displayName: modelDisplayName,
    runtimeConfig,
  };

  const request = {
    parent,
    pipelineJob,
  };

  const [response] = await pipelineClient.createPipelineJob(request);

  return sendResponse(res, {
    message: ModelTuningMessages.jobInitiated(response.name),
  });
} catch (err) {
  return sendError(
    err,
    new ApiError(
      httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      ModelTuningMessages.jobError


       )
      );
    }
  });
}

export default ModelTuningController;

I have the following error : You do not have permission to act as service_account: ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. (or it may not exist).
The problem is ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com is the project default service account. My guess it that my service account should act as the default service account of the project.
Does my service account is missing a role to execute the fine tuning job on Vertex AI ?
___________
EDIT
It seems like I needed to activate the Compute Engine API to have the default compute engine service account to make it work !
However I still have the error : Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: . It's hard to know which argument is invalid. This is the request JSON I send to the pipeline job :
{
  "parent": "projects/${projectID}/locations/us-central1",
  "pipelineJob": {
    "displayName": "fineTunedTest",
    "runtimeConfig": {
      "gcsOutputDirectory": "gs://${output}",
      "parameterValues": {
        "source_model": { "stringValue": "gemini-1.0-pro-002" },
        "train_dataset": { "stringValue": "gs://${input}/${file}" },
        "tuned_model_display_name": { "stringValue": "fineTunedTest" },
        "epochs": { "numberValue": 4 },
        "learning_rate_multiplier": { "numberValue": 1 }
      }
    }
  }
}


For the first problem : (You do not have permission to act as service_account: ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. (or it may not exist).)
I needed to activate the Compute Engine API to have the default compute engine service account. My service account only needed the roles Vertex AI Service Agent and Service Accounts User.
For the second problem : (Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT:) I needed to add the missing parameter templateUri to my pipelineJob object. His value is https://us-kfp.pkg.dev/ml-pipeline/large-language-model-pipelines/tune-large-model/v2.0.0 for text model and  https://us-kfp.pkg.dev/ml-pipeline/large-language-model-pipelines/tune-large-chat-model/v3.0.0 for chat model. See this for more informations.
My updated code is :
import aiplatform from '@google-cloud/aiplatform';

class ModelTuningController {
  initiateModelTuning = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { modelDisplayName = 'fineTunedTest' } = req.body;

    const { PipelineServiceClient } = aiplatform.v1;

    const location = 'us-central1';
    const project = 'projectID';
    const model = 'text-bison@001';

const pipelineClient = new PipelineServiceClient({
  apiEndpoint: `${location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com`,
  keyFilename: config.vector_store_key_filename,
});

const parameters = {
  source_model: { stringValue: model },
  train_dataset: {
    stringValue: 'gs://path/file.jsonl',
  },
  tuned_model_display_name: {
    stringValue: modelDisplayName,
  },
  epochs: {
    numberValue: 4,
  },
  learning_rate_multiplier: {
    numberValue: 1,
  },
};

const runtimeConfig = {
  gcsOutputDirectory: 'gs://output-path',
  parameterValues: parameters,
};

try {
  const parent = `projects/${project}/locations/${location}`;
  const pipelineJob = {
    displayName: modelDisplayName,
    templateUri: 'https://us-kfp.pkg.dev/ml-pipeline/large-language-model-pipelines/tune-large-model/v2.0.0',
    runtimeConfig,
  };

  const request = {
    parent,
    pipelineJob,
  };

  const [response] = await pipelineClient.createPipelineJob(request);

  return sendResponse(res, {
    message: ModelTuningMessages.jobInitiated(response.name),
  });
} catch (err) {
  return sendError(
    err,
    new ApiError(
      httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      ModelTuningMessages.jobError
       )
      );
    }
  });
    }

export default ModelTuningController;


Thanks. Enabling the Compute Engine API did the trick for me too.

The issue is not passing proper service account credential and granting proper IAM permission. There are two solutions (the second is preferred):

Grant additional permission to the the default compute service account.
Vertex AI pipeline will fallback to use default compute service account ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com when you don't specify a dedicated custom service account. To run Vertex pipeline, the default service account needs to have the following IAM permissions:


Vertex AI User (I think you are missing this one)
Service Account User
Storage Object Admin (optional when the pipeline needs to interact with storage bucket)
Try granting vertex AI user role to the default service account.


Use a dedicated custom service account. You can do this with GCP Application Default Credentials or pass credential to the API. Following is a sample snippet of passing your custom SA:

import aiplatform from '@google-cloud/aiplatform';
import { Auth, google } from "googleapis";

class ModelTuningController {
initiateModelTuning = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const { modelDisplayName = 'fineTunedTest' } = req.body;

  const { PipelineServiceClient } = aiplatform.v1;
  # set up auth
  // Path to your service account key file
  const keyFilename = '/path/to/your/service-account.json';

  // Create a new GoogleAuth instance with the service account key file
  const auth = new Auth.GoogleAuth({
   keyFile: keyFilename,
   scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  });

 // Get credentials
 const client = await auth.getClient();

 const clientOptions = {
  apiEndpoint: '${location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com',
  auth: client // Pass the authenticated client object here
 };

  const location = 'us-central1';
  const project = 'projectID';
  const model = 'text-bison@001';

  const pipelineClient = new PipelineServiceClient(clientOptions);
  ...

Keep in mind, the preferred authentication method depends on where and how you run the pipeline Node.js code. i.e running locally vs. running in GCP cloud function. Ideally, you don't want to export the service account key file for better security.

I tried the code you proposed but the auth type was not matching with the clientOptions. So I updated it use GoogleAuth from google-auth-library : "const auth = new GoogleAuth({ keyFilename: config.vector_store_key_filename, scopes: ['googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'], });" I pass this auth object to clientOptions. However I still have the error : You do not have permission to act as service_account: ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. (or it may not exist).

Also Vertex AI Service Agent role have more right than Vertex AI User. I need the permission for aiplatform.pipelineJobs.create and both have it. So my service should have the right to do that

Did you try option #1? Grant service account ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com the Vertex AI User role?

I didn't because it would not be secure to add this role to the default service account. That's why I wanted to use a dedicated service account.

And I can't see the ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account (the project default service account) on the IAM page. Also with commande line : gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding 
${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com 
--member=serviceAccount:${serviceAccountName} 
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser 
--project=${projectID} it says the ${projectID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account doesn't exist

It seems like I needed to activate the Compute Engine API to have the default compute engine service account to make it work !

I made edit to my original post because I still have invalid argument
